# android - overriding the back button

Tags: android

I have a `webView` inside an Activity's layout. If back button is pressed, I want that view to disappear and other views to become visible, to I did the following:

```
    @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && web.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE) {
        restoreInitalState(); // set Visibility of Views
        APP_CONSTANTS.LOGIN_OP_CANCELLED(getApplicationContext()); // inform the user that the current operation was cancelled
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}
```

it works BUT it finishes the Activity immediately after calling my methods, like if the back button was pressed 2 times. I need to keep the current Activity and just call my methods mentioned above. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return false. Change this:

```
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && web.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE) {
    restoreInitalState(); // set Visibility of Views
    APP_CONSTANTS.LOGIN_OP_CANCELLED(getApplicationContext()); // inform the user that the current operation was cancelled
}
```

to this:

```
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && web.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE) {
    restoreInitalState(); // set Visibility of Views
    APP_CONSTANTS.LOGIN_OP_CANCELLED(getApplicationContext()); // inform the user that the current operation was cancelled
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct method is:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && web.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE) {
        restoreInitalState(); // set Visibility of Views
        APP_CONSTANTS.LOGIN_OP_CANCELLED(getApplicationContext()); 
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just use the method, `onBackPressed()` in youe `Activity` class ,that's the simplest way to Override it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the callback method you are looking for is [`onBackPressed`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29).

But your current solution should work as well, you just need to return true inside your if-block otherwise the event will be propagated to another callback.